# UIView coordinates when using autloyout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, frame

I need to draw a line below UITextField. I'm using the most simple method by creating a UIView with a height of 1. The problem is that the UITextField is positioned in IB using autolayout and it seems like it's frame is undetermined when -viewDidLoad is called. Previously I used this way of drawing lines where all views where laid out using code. How can I determine the coordinates of my UITextField in this case?

I use this code to create a line

```
- (void)drawLineBelowTextFied:(UITextField *)textField {

#define LINE_MARGIN 20

//draw a line

UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(LINE_MARGIN, textField.frame.origin.y + textField.frame.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width-LINE_MARGIN*2, 1)];
line.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
line.alpha = 0.25f;
line.clipsToBounds = NO;
[_loginView insertSubview:line belowSubview:textField];
```

Line appears nowhere. If I replace y coordinate with a constant it appears.

Comment: After you doing drawLineBelowTextField inside viewDidLoad() or viewDidAppear() ? In viewDidLoad, the frame of the view may or may not be initialized yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never mix auto layout and setting frames from code. You should create a constraint (from editor or in code) specifying the distance between those two components and sizes if required.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to do that. Now I see where I was wrong and why.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the Apple's documentation, an *UIView* with *Autolayout* will have it's expected position and size after *NSLayoutConstraints* are applied in the *layoutSubviews* method. At the *UIViewController* level you are notified about this in *viewDidLayoutSubviews*. It's important to remember, that code inside *viewDidLayoutSubviews* is executed every time the view's bounds change.